# How to check if a Swift function was called in Objective C?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

This MockApiClient is being used to call the function `executeRequest` on `ViewController.m` in the `viewDidLoad` method.

`MockApiClient.Swift`

```
import Foundation

class MockApiClient: NSObject
{

override init ()
    {
    print("Initializer called in Mock API client")
    
    }

@objc func executeRequest() 
    {
    print("The execute request has been called")

    }

}
```

`ViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

MockApiclient *client = [MockApiclient new];

//Prints "Initializer called in Mock API client" in console window

[client executeRequest];

}
```

How can I check that the function `executeRequest` was called?

I tried:

`Viewcontroller.m`

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

MockApiclient *client = [MockApiclient new];

[client executeRequest];
    
if ([client executeRequest]) {
    //
}
```

Debugger:

`Statement requires expression of scalar type ('void' invalid)`

[image]

Comment: The compiler is telling you that `executeRequest` returns `void` and you can't use a `void` in an `if` statement.  What exactly are you trying to test?  If you call `[client executeRequest]` then the `executeRequest` function *will be called*.

Comment: Heyo. Am looking to check if the `executeRequest` function was called. The goal is to call it from `ViewController` , and check if it was called from a different ViewController. Right now I'm just checking if the compiler accepts the logical condition before trying it in another VC.

Comment: Then you need to inject functionality that somehow "records" the fact that the function was called. This is an odd thing to want to do (especially because if you call the function you already _know_ it was called), but it certainly can be done.

Comment: Appreciate it. And agreed. Am currently considering a BOOLEAN option. Am open to other options.

Comment: Note that even if you change the function to return a boolean, calling it to check its return value calls the function *again*.  If you want to check that it has been called from somewhere other than where it is called, then you will need to set some flag or similar elsewhere so you can check that;  You need to check for whatever effect calling this function has on your app's state, and make it have an effect on your app's state if it doesn't already.

Comment: Agreed. Great breakdown. I think using an existing class in the project that can check for boolean values using NSUserDefaults will be the trick. Ty. Update in progress... `- (BOOL)joinedChat
{
 return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:JoinedChatKey];
}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like that

```
import Foundation

@objc protocol ApiClientProtocol : NSObjectProtocol {
    func executeRequest()
}

class MockApiClient: NSObject {

    @objc public var executeRequestCalled = false

    @objc func executeRequest()  {
        executeRequestCalled = true
    }

}
```

then

```
Viewcontroller.m

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MockApiClient *clientImpl = [MockApiclient new]; // Dependency Injection is implied, can use clientImpl direct
    id<ApiClientProtocol> *client = clientImpl;

    [client executeRequest];
    
    if (clientImpl.executeRequestCalled) {
      // it's called
    } else {
      // it isn't
    }
}
```

Isn't the best solution, but it works